# PyQGIS QgsVectorLayer.uniqueValues() override active object filtering

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, filter, definition-query, unique-value

This code snippet gives me the unique values for a vector layers attribute called `myfieldname`

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
attrIndex = l.fieldNameIndex('myfieldname')
uniValues = l.uniqueValues(attrIndex)
```

With an active object filter I only get the unique values of a subset matching the filter criteria.

Is there a way to override this behaviour, in order to get all unique values for an attribute (of the complete layer) even with an active object filter?

(applies also for `featureCount()` etc.)

Comment: Is the initial subset filter being applied by code?

Comment: Yes it is. There must be a flag or something that tells pyqgis to ignore an existing filter, like the checkbox in the object filter dialog does.

Comment: Can you just clear the filter before running the unique value function and then reply the filter (e.g. clear filter LYR.setSubsetString(''))?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need use a filter expression.You can try this.
For example

**1: Step.**

Apply your filter.

```
iface=qgis.utils.iface
l = iface.activeLayer()
l.setSubsetString('name='"\'Balneario Las Arenas\'")

mView= iface.layerTreeView()
node = iface.layerTreeView().currentNode()
nodeslist=mView.selectedLayerNodes()
newValue = node.customProperty("showFeatureCount", 0 ) 
for value in nodeslist:
    value.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", int(newValue));
```

**2: Step.**

Apply filter expression.

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
selection =l.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression('name='"\'Balneario Las Arenas\'")))   
for feat in selection:
    attrIndex = l.fieldNameIndex('myfieldname')
    uniValues = l.uniqueValues(attrIndex)
```

it's a suggestion.